# Using IP to ping a real Android device that is plugged by USB from computer

Tags: usb, connection-issues

I plugged my Android tablet to the computer with USB cable and looked at the IP of Android device and tried something like `ping 160.xxx.yyy.zzz` on the computer. There is no response.

I wonder, does being in a huge network that prevent one machine to see the other one affect to 
pinging from one machine to another, even they are connected by a USB cable?

Comment: Did you connect the Android tablet via reverse tethering over USB or what network does it use?

Comment: @onik  i do not know what is reverse tethering.

Comment: Just connecting your Android with a PC over USB does not establish IP connectivity. Reverse tethering would be one possibility to achieve that, but there are also other means.

Comment: @Flow thanks. is there a mean that not need root access

Comment: @Flow i have WiFi both on my Android device and PC within a huge network that i think no device can ping another. But do you think in a small network like a home network, can i ping from my PC to my Android device?

Comment: @merveotesi If your Android device is connected to same network to which your PC also connected, then PING **should** work. But there is no relation between plugging USB and PING test.

Comment: @KeshavaGN There is no guarantee that ping works inside any network as long as the two devices are inside it. Especially in large infrastructures, there can be separate VLANs, rules against ICMP packets in firewalls etc.

Comment: @onik do you think adb connect can act as a connection like reverse tethering provides?

Comment: @merveotesi No, that's the opposite of what `adb connect` does. It makes an ADB connection to an IP address you can reach on the network, so that you can debug on the device as if it were plugged in by USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your network is correctly setup, and both devices are on the same network then you can ping an Android device just fine. I've just tested it on my office network.

If your network administrator has configured the network such that devices can't ping each other, then obviously it won't work. Similarly, it probably won't work if your phone is on mobile data, since most carriers don't allow incoming pings to devices on their network.

Connecting the device with USB makes no difference at all: pinging is a network operation, so it goes over the network connecting the two devices.

Comment: Also worth noting: `160.xxx.xxx.xxx` doesn't sound like a local network address. It's most likely the address of the *mobile* data connection, where `ping` (and other services) directed *toward* the device often is blocked by the carriers routers.